# Update multiple records in one query in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

lets say I have a Array of Hashes like this

```
users_ar = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Luke',
   age: 19
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Vader',
   age: 44
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Yoda',
   age: 129
 }
]
```

The id is their id in the User model.

How can i update all records at once in ruby on rails (if i don't need to validate the records) for performance reasons if i have thousands of records to update?

I'd like to find existing records by id and update name and age. Im looking for something like this:

```
users_to_update.update_all(users_ar)
```

My rails version is 5.2.3 and I'm using MySQL.

Thanks, Andreas

Comment: What will you be "updating"?  The name?  The age?  Maybe even the id??  Or did you mean `INSERT` 3 new rows instead of `UPDATE` 3 existing rows?  Or, maybe, "upsert" wherein you either add new row(s) or modify existing row(s) based on some unique key (presumably the `id`).

Comment: Is that "array of hashes" keyed off `id`?  Or `name`?

Comment: I have updated my question. I like to find the records by id and update name and age.

Answer (score 1):

The `activerecord-import` gem is probably what you need if you're looking to do large batch updates with good performance: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: Shouldn't that link say **matched** instead of **violated** where it says "... which allows you to specify fields whose values should be updated if a primary or unique key constraint is **violated**"??

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
    (id, name, age)
      VALUES
    (1, 'Luke', 19),
    (2, 'Vader', 44),
    (3, 'Yoda', 129)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        name = VALUES(name),
        age = VALUES(age);
```

Although this looks like an "upsert", it is the fastest way I know of to just Update several rows at once.  In your case, all the rows already exist (according to the unique `id`), so it proceeds to Update each of the rows.

(No, I don't know how to say this in RoR.  The link provided by bugged may answer this.)